# Validation Rule As a Boolean (or comparable variable) VBA Access

Tags: vba, validation, ms-access, boolean

I have a form that creates user accounts, and I want the "Create My Account" button to be disabled until all the fields have satisfied their validation rules.
Is there some manner of coding comparable to:

```
If Me.Field.ValidationRule = True Then
-code-
```

It doesn't have to be in boolean form, that's just the first way I can think of doing it.
I don't know if it makes a difference, but the fields are not directly linked to the table; after the "Create My Account" button is pressed, the values are transferred. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `and` operator. So you will have something like

```
If rule1 And rule2 And rule3 then
    'code here
End if
```

Where ruleX is any boolean expression.